# Command line arguments or reading file

Tags: c, file, command-line-arguments

I need to process 10 values. Which way would be better? Getting them as command line arguments or instead reading from a file?
Using C by the way.

Comment: @Radek: Alas, the general rule is no migrations to beta site. 'Course, it has been broken from time to time.

Comment: @dmckee it cannot be migrated to UX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make them as command-line arguments, then you could do it both ways... i.e.

```
 a.out 1 2 hello abc ...
```

or

```
a.out \`cat file_with_arguments.txt\
```